# How to add an Artifactory WAR as a Gradle dependency

Tags: java, spring, gradle, artifactory

I'm working on a Spring MVC project (using Gradle) to produce a template to be integrated on different projects. The template project contains few HTML files and some classes to handle the properties. I've configured the artifactory-gradle-plugin to generate and publish a WAR containing my HTML files and classes. Everything works just fine and my WAR and POM files are now available under my Artifactory server. Here's a part of my build.gradle file

```
war {
    rootSpec.exclude('**/*.properties')
    [...]
    rootSpec.exclude('**/test/**')
    rootSpec.exclude('**/*.jar')
}

artifactory {
    publish {
        contextUrl = "myurl"  
        repository {
            repoKey = 'myrepo'
            username = "myuser"
            password = "mypasswd"
            maven = true
        }
        defaults {
            publications ('mavenJava')
        }
    }
}
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.web
        }
    }
 }
```

Unfortunately when I try to add this artifact as dependency on an other project, Gradle successfully finds the WAR but nothing is integrated in the project. I can't find any HTML, classes or war files in the project.

```
dependencies {
    compile(group: 'test.spring', name: 'test-layout', version: '0.0.1', ext: 'war')
}
```

Is there something missing or am I completely of the track with this?

Answer (score 1):

It does not make sense to add dependency to a war file since that is a packaging for an application server and not for other projects.

I suggest you also publish other artifacts from your original project, and instead import them as dependencies.

An alternative would be to unpack the war in a separate task but that is not needed when you have control over the source project.

Comment: "I suggest you also publish other artifacts from your original project" My goal is to package the classes and the html files in the same artifact. Do you know if it's possible and how?

Comment: First of all. WHY do you want to add stuff from the war file and what will you use it for? Classes should be imported using a dependency on a normal jar file, not a war file. And how do you know that the war is NOT in the dependency tree? Have you checked with the 'gradle dependencies' command?

Comment: I'm trying to add HTML files to an artifact (no mater if it's a War or a Jar). These HTML files and classes will then be available in other projects (as templates for the layout). Do you know if there's a way to achieve it?

Comment: I would suggest you use zip as the archive type, it is easier to understand that you are going to re-use the items in it. Also Gradle has some good features in the Copy-task when it comes to dealing with zip files.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after asking the same question on the Gradle forum, it seems that there is no easy way to achieve this using one single artifact without loosing all dependencies (special thanks to Lance_Java). It sounds like I have to create a JAR and a ZIP artifact (see the zip references as described in the previous @Joachim Nilsson post)

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-add-an-artifactory-war-as-a-gradle-dependency/19804/4

My final solution will be to simply deploy my templates under a "commons" web repository and deploy my configuration classes in a JAR artifact.